# Issue with importing model to xna

Tags: xna, models, blender

I am creating a model with Blender which looks like this:

[image]

and I am importing it into an XNA project.
There seems to be some kind of transparency issue.
The model looks like that:

[image]

When the camera looks on one side, the side is not shown.
Why do I have this problem and what can I do to fix it?

PS: I am using a custom Effect but I don't think that the issue has something to do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it might be a face culling issue. Try turning off face culling:

```
 GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;
```

Comment: You are perfectly right. I thought it would be a DepthStencil issue but it wasn't. The model still has a small problem (I don't know why this triangle is rendered completely different) but I suppose I have to check my Blender model. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Settings the cullmode to none is only a workaround. There is a problem within Blender that causes problems during export. Maybe you can send this model to blender community? So they are able to identify this bug in their software. 
By the way, you should never disable backfaceculling during your whole drawings, because you loose performance. So your code should look like the following:

```
//store last state
var oldResterizerState = GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState;
//set rasterizer to "solve" your bug
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;
//draw your buggy model now
....
//reset graphicsdevice to old state
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = oldRasterizerState;
```

Comment: I suggested disabling culling in order to help diagnose the problem, rather than as a solution

Comment: I know that culling is going to slow down the performance but right now I just want to play around with Blender. I'll check if its a bug or if I do something wrong

Comment: @Ken: I don't meant you where wrong. But I recently I saw code of a colleague that disables culling in the whole simulation without care about the consequences in order so "solve" such problems. So I wanted to give a hint